# Malloced char* but crashes and says it's not malloced

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

I'm mallocing a string

```
int main(){
    int buf = 1024;
    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char*) * buf);

    //CODE
    scanf("%s", input);
    //MORE CODE

    free(input);
}
```

If I don't set the input string to anything it works however, it crashes when its set to something.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100f01efa: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I think I'm doing it correctly but not really sure why it crashes.

Comment: I assume you're using the pointer in the MORE CODE part. That would be good to see also. Anything shown here won't show the problem.

Comment: Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your entire program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to post the answer to my problem as I figured it out a while back.

I needed to change the sizeof to get the size of a single char, not a pointer.

```
char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * buf);
```

Comment: You are right. However `sizeof(char)` is always 1. And `sizeof(char*)` is likely to be more (often 4 or 8). So your original code just `malloc`-ed more memory than necessary, so that was not the real cause of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `malloc` characters not character pointers.

i.e. change

```
sizeof(char*)
```

to

```
1
```

Or just put

```
char *input = malloc(buf);
```

Comment: While this is true, it still doesn't explain the issue in question. Allocating more memory than needed won't cause issues releasing it.